# How do I get a pandas MultiIndex level as a series, keeping the original MultiIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a MultiIndex like:

```py
multiindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a', 'b'], range(3)], names=['first', 'second'])
```

```
MultiIndex([('a', 0),
            ('a', 1),
            ('a', 2),
            ('b', 0),
            ('b', 1),
            ('b', 2)],
           names=['first', 'second'])
```

How do I get a Series or DataFrame like this?

```py
              second
first second        
a     0            0
      1            1
      2            2
b     0            0
      1            1
      2            2
```

Asking because I want to use this index level to compute some other stuff.

Note: I do not want to add a new column to the original DataFrame.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.to_frame.html) and slicing of the desired level:

```
import pandas as pd

# set up example MultiIndex
multiindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a', 'b'], range(3)],
                                        names=['first', 'second'])

# convert to DataFrame
df = multiindex.to_frame()[['second']]
```

A more manual alternative:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(multiindex.get_level_values(1), index=multiindex)
```

Output:

```
              second
first second        
a     0            0
      1            1
      2            2
b     0            0
      1            1
      2            2
```